# Pre-decided keys in realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When using a realtime database, I can create a new record like this:

```
let newRecord = dbReference.push();
newRecord.set({myField:myFieldValue,myOtherField:myOtherFieldValue});
```

*.push()* creates a new record with an automatically generated key.

And this works. But there are cases where one wish to decide the key to be used, rather than have it automatically generated.

What is the proper way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
const newRecordKey = dbReference.push().key;
dbReference.child(newRecordKey).set({
  myField: myFieldValue,
  myOtherField: myOtherFieldValue
})
```

If you are looking to access the reference key that is automatically generated you can do this, otherwise, you could initialize newRecordKey with the value you prefer and that should be the object key.

Comment: Where are you using the key of your choice in your code?
For example if you want push to use the key 'AKH873' instead of a random key. What do you do?

Comment: `const newRecordKey = 'AKH873` initializing the key variable to a specific key should give you the result you are looking for, If I understood correctly.